# Regular expression pattern not working, why?

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match string like the following :

```
"§{characters.characters}"
"§{characters_characters}"
"§{characters_characters.characters}"
```

etc

I did this :

```
Pattern.compile("\\§\\{[a-zA-Z]+([_\\.][a-zA-Z]+)*\\}")
```

But it doesn't work at all. Anyone knows why ?

If I put `Pattern.compile("\\§\\{([a-zA-Z]+)([_\\.][a-zA-Z]+)*\\}")` only strings like "character" are ok. But don't understand why either...

Comment: What about the `\\{` & `\\}`?

Comment: This tool might be useful : http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 3):

to match your test strings

```
[a-zA-Z]+([_\\.][a-zA-Z]+)*
```

works just fine, `\\§\\{` and `\\}` aren't characters in your test string, so they don't match, your regex is looking for something like

```
\§\{characters_characters.characters\}
```

see `[a-zA-Z]+([_\\.][a-zA-Z]+)*` in action at http://regexr.com?325e8

and `\\§\\{([a-zA-Z]+)([_\\.][a-zA-Z]+)*\\}` at http://regexr.com?325ee

---

**EDIT**

per your comment, `§{([a-zA-Z]+)([_\\.][a-zA-Z]+)*}` should do it http://regexr.com?325gp

Comment: Thanks, just forgot characters § { and } in the Strings I want to match... Will check your urls. And I edited my original post.

Comment: @Lyth use `§{([a-zA-Z]+)([_\\.][a-zA-Z]+)*}`, I've updated my answer with that & a demo

Comment: I tried the tools I was given and it came out that my Pattern.compile("\\§\\{([a-zA-Z]+)([_\\.][a-zA-Z]+)*\\}") should be working since the pattern \§\{([a-zA-Z]+)([_\.][a-zA-Z]+)*\} matches strings like char.char_char etc. Then, your tool shows that §{([a-zA-Z]+)([_\.][a-zA-Z]+)*} works too. When I try this one I get the error "Illegal repetition near index 0" in my program. When I use the first one, some strings are not matched like a simple "test_string"...

Comment: if you want it to match with or without the section mark & curly brackets try this `(§{)?([a-zA-Z]+)([_\\.][a-zA-Z]+)*}?` http://regexr.com?326j3 ... are the section & curly escaped?

Comment: Sorry, once again forgot the characters §{}. Meant "§{test_string}". I think my problem doesn't come from the regular expression after all.